# getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML Removing <head>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm running the below script to replace the contents of my `<body>` tags.  It works but it is also removing the contents of my `<head>` tags.

Any idea why this might be happening?

```
if ($(window).width() < 977) {
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML="<div style='text-align: center; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; background-color: none;'><iframe id='id-name' name='name' src='http://example.com'></iframe></div>";
}
```

**UPDATE**

What's with the down votes?  Shall I just close the question?

I'm trying to change the html inside my body tag when the window width is below a certain width, to contain a different iframe.

The problem is it's also removing the contents of my `<head>` tags

Comment: The question is not at all clear. What is it that you expect to happen when you replace all the HTML content in the `<body>` element with new content? *edit* ok fixed broken markdown. So what does the original HTML look like? How can you tell that the `<head>` is being overwritten?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? innerHTML does just that... it sets the content of that tag to whatever is in ""

Comment: When I run http://jsfiddle.net/akZ6u/, I can clearly see (by inspecting the elements), that the content of `head` is not changed. So either your observation is wrong, or even if it is correct, `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML` is most likely not responsible for what you see and the problem must be somewhere else. Since you don't provide any context information, it is not really possible for us to help you.

Comment: ok, thanks.  There must being something else causing the issue here.  It would be too large a scenario to troubleshoot on this post. It's a Magento instalation with other scripts & extensions. I thought it may of had something to do with my script as it only arose when I ran this script.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you meant by "it works" but here is what I see from the code:
you are ***replacing***, not *appending*, the content of the body tag. If there is any other content in the body tag you want to keep, you might want to extract that portion first then join with the new content you want to add.

Comment: "it works" means it set out to do what I wanted it to acomplish & it replaced the contents of the <body> tags.  The problem is it also removing the contents of my <head> tags?

Comment: I don't see how this answer got up votes, it belongs in the comments

Comment: I understand that, but this could be an answer to the original question. Rather than that, my rep was less than 50.